# Springboot: How to execute custom mongodb query by springboot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

I want to find a list of models matched either field `nameEnglish` or `nameChinese` by a keyword. I spent more than an hour googling but I cannot do it. Please help.

Springboot Mongo starter example https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

The custom query I want to execute and return a list result

```
db.mymodel.aggregate([ 
    {
        $match: {
            $or :[
             { nameChinese: /門/ },
             { nameEnglish: /cocina/i }
            ]
        }
    },
    { $sort: {nameEnglish: 1} }
])
```

My best trial so far

```
interface MyModelRepository : MongoRepository<MyModel, String> {
    @Query(value = "{ '\$match': { \$or: [ {'nameEnglish': { \$regex: ?0 } }, {'nameChinese': { \$regex: ?0 } } ] }")
    fun findByMyQuery(name: String): List<MyModel>
}
```

For the regex, I also want it to be case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after a hot water shower ( and one day of googling and reading documents). Hope this help someone in the future.

```
@Query(value = "{ \$or: [ {'nameEnglish': { \$regex: ?0, \$options: 'i'}}, {'nameChinese': { \$regex: ?0 }}] }", sort = "{nameEnglish: 1}")
```